# How can I insert a background image in google app engine using index.css for guestbook application?

Tags: css, image, google-app-engine, background

In main.css I have this code:

```
body {
  font-family: Comic Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #AACCFF;
}
```

this produces a light blue color as the background. How can I change this code so that it inputs a background image instead of a background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) css property.

Your body rule would change to something like:

```
body {
    font-family: Comic Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('images/my_background.jpg');
}
```

You might also want to look in to [background-repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) css property to control how the image repeats itself.

Comment: I understand now. You have to use this code:

  background-image: url(../stylesheets/goku-wallpaper-2.jpg);

basically, you go up from the directory where the CSS is located, then go into the file where CSS is located and then the image should be there if you saved it there. Thanks man

Comment: Yeah, all URLs in a CSS file are relative to the location of the css file.  so if your css is at `/css/site.css` and your image is at `/images/my_background.jpg`, then the url in the CSS file could either be `/images/my_background.jpg` (where its not relative), or `../images/my_background.jpg` (which is relative to the CSS file).  If my answer solved your problem, please accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you will need to put somewhere your files first:

say folder: assets/images/ contains file my_background.jpg

Then edit your app.yaml:

```
handlers:

- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
```

and then:

```
body {
    font-family: Comic Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('assets/images/my_background.jpg');
}
```

Done

Comment: I feel like this should be the correct answer. I came across the first answer and was stumped for the longest time until I came across this answer. As soon as I added the handler it worked.